# Broken Help Link

Tags: search-builder

https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/stable/the-user-interface/searching

Search Builder Help link is broken, referenced here:[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SE!  Thanks for reporting that.  There are several changes happening with the documentation infrastructure resulting in this glitch.  Apparently it should be fixed soon.  Meanwhile if you substitute 'latest' for 'stable' in the URL you can get to the documentation.